# OAuth 2.0 postman automation

Tags: oauth-2.0, automation, postman

I am using Postman to automate my rest api call 
currently we have changed to this Oauth 2.0 with that I am unable to automate or run the collection .

As I have to manually request an access token  and then log in to the UI and then copy the token or use the token .

I was wondering if you have any alternative suggestion as to how we can automate this OAuth 2 token in postman

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You say you have to log in somewhere first in order to get the token, I guess it is dynamic?
Then use the Pre-request script tab and add the steps for logging in and fecthing the token before each use, if possible. That can then easily be added as a variable and then passed as the Access Token.